# Linq to Entities Binding, Filtering and Editing in WinForms

Tags: binding, datagrid, .net-3.5, linq-to-entities

1) Binding to The following populates a READ ONLY WinFrms grid:

```
    Dim query = (From profile _
              In db.profile _
              Where profile.employee.employeeId = employeeID _
              Select profile.description)

    Me.DataGridView.DataSource = profileQueryList
```

2) Binding to the entity itself makes the WinForms grid EDITABLE, but unfiltered:

```
    Me.DataGridView.DataSource = db.profile
```

I need something that combines the filtering feature of #1 with the editable feature of #2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution!  It's documented in:
[Linq to Entities Filtering an Entity Dynamic/Strongly Typed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784363/linq-to-entities-filtering-an-entity-dyamic-strongly-typed)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use an explicit `ToList()` call.

```
Me.DataGridView.DataSource = query.ToList()
```

I guess that else only the expression tree of the query is bound and the entities are only fetched on demand.

Comment: Have you tried inserting a BindingSource between control and collection?

Answer (score -1):

Don't bind directly to the queryable. Instead, you need to go through the [EntityDataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.entitydatasource.aspx) class. Note, especially, [this article on how to filter data with this control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488531.aspx).

Comment: EntityDataSource is part of System.Web.UI.Webcontrols.  I'm working in a Winforms environment.  Is there an equivilent?

Comment: Poster asking about WinForms, not ASP.NET Web forms